# Stress in horizontal bars

Tags: continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

Imagine we have an horizontal bar. My teacher expresses the tensions along the longitudinal axis by this way

$\sigma_{xx}=A(x)y+B(x)$

He doesn't give any motivation behind this. So, is this general? and how is it justified?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? It looks like it might be for combined tension/bending of a beam, but it's hard to tell from your question.

Comment: Wouldn't this be a 1st order aproximation on the strain tensor?

Comment: My teacher has just told me that if we have a bar horizontally placed that is bending whose cross section suffers longitudinal and transversal forces and a bending moment, this is the more general form of the longitudinal component of the tension tensor, if the vertical tension o the cross section is assumed to be uniformly distributed (which we assume).

Answer (score 1):

All that this is saying is that the stress is a function of $x$ due to general transverse and normal loading. The linear dependence on $y$ is due to the approximation of small-deflection beam bending. The stress due to pure bending is

$$
\sigma_{xx}(x,y) = \frac{M(x)y}{I(x)}
$$

$M(x)$ (moment of force) is determined by the loading, and $I(x)$ (2nd moment of area) is determined by the geometry. The $B(x)$ in your equation is caused by (possibly distributed) axial loads, e.g. gravity on a vertical bar.